# Scrapy not working on patta site

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to use scrapy-spider on patta.nl to get all the products from the latest products and to store them into a DB.

Some sites into my monitor are working, but someone such as Patta is not working and not uploading nothing to the db.
This is my function:

```
class PattaSpider(Spider):

name = "PattaSpider"
allowded_domains = ["patta.nl"]
start_urls = [PattaURL]

def __init__(self):
    logging.critical("Patta STARTED.")

def parse(self, response):
    products = Selector(response).xpath('//ul[@class="products-grid EqualRow grid-4-columns label-type-2 top-right first last odd isotope"]')

    for product in products:
        item = PattaItem()
        item['name'] = product.xpath('//h3[@class="product-name"]/a').extract_first()
        item['link'] = product.xpath('//h3[@class="product-name"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        yield item

    yield Request(PattaURL, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True, priority=3)
```

Can someone help me solving this problem? Thanks

Comment: Including the exact url you're trying to scrape would probably be a good idea.

Comment: @stranac startURL is the correct URL :)

Comment: `PattaURL` doesn't tell us what the url actually is, we need to be able to test the code in order to debug it.

Comment: @stranac you’re right but it’s a code that is implemented in 3 different files, tomorrow morning I will upload some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems with your code:

1. your `products` is just a single `ul`
2. you're using wrong `@class` for the `ul` (check source HTML code)
3. you need to use relative XPath expression for each item

   ```
   products = response.xpath('//ul[contains(@class,"products-grid")]/li')

   for product in products:
       item = PattaItem()
       item['name'] = product.xpath('.//h3[@class="product-name"]/a/text()').extract_first()
       item['link'] = product.xpath('.//h3[@class="product-name"]/a/@href').extract_first()
       yield item
   ```